# Combo box that finds a record, is bringing up multiple fields

Tags: ms-access, combobox, ms-access-2007

I have a combo box on a form that when you pick the month it will brings up all the jobs for that month in a subform.

This was working perfectly until I wanted to change some fields so I deleted the combo box and when I put a new one it brings up the month for every single record, i.e.

```
January 
<br>January 
<br>January
<br>April
<br>April
<br>May 
<br>May
<br>May 

etc etc..
```

How do I change it so it just brings up only one January and so on?

Answer (score 0):

Please post your table structure, so we can determine what the problem is.

Without it I will do a wild guess and assume that the DISTINCT clause in the combobox query is missing.

What you have:

```
SELECT Jobs.JobDate FROM Jobs;
```

What you should have:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(Jobs.JobDate) FROM Jobs;
```

But again: if this does not solve your problem, post the table definition.

Comment: Im not to sure what you mean by table definition but these are the fields in the table: Job No, Year, Month, Company ID, Company Contact Name, Job Description, Amount Quoted, Amount To Invoice, Job Completed, Invoice No

Comment: I mean: the names and data types of the columns in the table that you populate the combobox with.

Comment: well when i made the combo box all i did was click the option 'find the record in my form when i click a option in the combo box'- then from the list of options it gives me Is selected 'Month Initiated'. which is text format. Which on the table i just used a look up data and just entered my own months in.